# function vector says it's not a function

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I'm trying to associate a eventListener onclick, for each of my tabs.
The problem I'm facing and I've seen different answers but didn't find myself able to adapt to my situation, so I'm basicly trying to pass as a paremeter to the onClick function, a variable which depends on the for Index. I've tried to save it on a inner function, but in the end I didn't achieve anything. Currently I'm at this point, and it says that paramsi is not a function!

```
                var i = 0;
    var params = [];
    for (i; i < returnableInfo.length; i++) {

        var widgetActiveTab = document.createElement('li');
        widgetActiveTab.className = "tabsList";
        widgetActiveTab.id = "li" + returnableInfo[i].id;

        var widgetTabContent = document.createElement('a');
        widgetTabContent.id = "li_a" + returnableInfo[i].id;



        function createfunc(i) {
            return function () {
                return returnableInfo[i];
            };
        }

        params[i] = createfunc(i);


        widgetTabContent.addEventListener('click', function () {

            executeIfFacetasSensoresResponseReady(params[i]());
        });
```

Comment: You have a closure problem, but you haven't really solved it, you've just moved things around

Comment: You basically need another function like `createfunc()` that builds the "click" handler.